# Is it possible to just use mysql queries to group by a time frame?

Tags: mysql, time, group-by

Basically I have a database contain some kind of logs, each record has an IP address field, I need to produce a report that find any IP addresses that logged more than 10 times within an hour. I have not yet written any queries like this before, so I wonder if it's possible just writing queries before I start writing code.

table columns:

```
ip
time
```

Comment: You will need to list the columns for the records. You can of course select by date range if you are logging the date

Comment: and time is a unix timestamp, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct ip
from logs_table
group by ip, date_format(`time`, '%Y%M%d%H')
having count(*) > 10
```

Comment: was he asking for any items having ten within the last hour?

Comment: Hi I need to get the records appear more than 10 times within one hour

Comment: your answer makes sense, I will try it out then mark it as an answer, cheers!

Comment: This query will not find log entries that happen across hours. Example: 7 log entries 10:50 and 7 log entries at 11:10. This will not be recognized since these entries happened in 2 different hours.